# Excel: Forming different sums in one column with interruptions and different lengths

Tags: excel, excel-formula, sum

I've been trying to solve this proble for few days now, but I haven't found a solution for it yet.

- My column B contains dates
- in C time in 15 minute intervals.
- in column D are values for each time, but there are interruptions that vary in lenght. And the length of the periods which values occur are also different in length.

So now I need to sum up  the respective blocks in which values occur per block.  After that an average of the sums must be calculated.

[image]

That means: sum until no more value is available and start summing if there is a value until there is no value left and so on..

But which formula (without VBA?) do I have to use?

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: If you want the sum(s) in column E as a single cell then a formula would do; to put the sum into a merged cell, VBA is required.

Comment: I only want the sum(s) in a single cell. What kind of formula do I have to use in this case?

Comment: What's the point of a formula, if you have to manually merge cells for the sum anyways? If you want to do that, might as well use vba or display the result in a different format

Comment: @Rawrplus that means it isn't possible to sum up the different blocks with a formula (for example with IF) and it has to be done manually? Because I have a huge kind of data and I don't want to do that manually, because then it would take days to finish it.So I need to use vba? And how is this working? Because I haven't worked that often with VBA

Comment: It is possible to do it for bottom-most (non-empty) cell  - checked @Jeeped's  answer, but I can't think of a way for a merged cell using purely formula. With VBA it would be possible. Though to be fair, it's best to stay away from merged cells altogether

Answer (score 1):

Put this in E2 then fill down.

```
=IF(AND(D2<>"", D3=""), SUM(INDEX(D$1:D2, AGGREGATE(14, 7, ROW(A:A)/(ISTEXT(D$1:D2)+ISBLANK(D$1:D2)), 1)):D2), TEXT(,))
```

[image]

Comment: Great! Thanks it almost works. I only have the problem that it does not make the sums new every time, but it always adds the previous total, even though I have adopted the formula exactly as you inserted it here. Do you know what that could be? Is there any difference in Excel compared to another country?